# Faster mod operation for large numbers in Java

Tags: java, biginteger, modulo

I need to check whether X is divisible by Y or Not. I don't need the actual remainder in other cases.

I'm using the "mod" operator.

```
if (X.mod(Y).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
{
     do something
}
```

Now, I'm interested only when X is divisible by Y, I don't need the actual remainder on other cases.

Finding a faster way to check divisibility when the dividend is fixed. More precisely, to check for large number (potential to be prime) with many smaller primes before going to Lucas-Lehmer test.

I was just wondering, can we make some assumption (Look ahead type) depending on the last one or two digits of X & Y and we can make a decision to go for the mod or not (when there is no chance to get zero).

Comment: Is there a reason you want to optimize this much?  Or is this a case of premature optimization?

Comment: Whatever you might come up with is very unlikely to be faster than just doing the mod.

Comment: There are some options but you could probably get more out of taking a wider view. How are X and Y calculated? Do they have useful properties? Is Y "fixed" for long enough that precalculating something for it makes sense?

Comment: totally unrelated to the solution you are asking for, but this kind of arithmetic operation is an ideal candidate for memoisation. Memoisation is a technique when you cache the input of a function with the output, so that subsequent calls to the function doesn't execute it but returns the answer from cache directly. Might be faster than the modulus if the calls are being made with same numbers

Comment: Have you consider bit-shifting?

Comment: X is fixed, Y will change, they are very large, the mod operation take sometimes 10 milliseconds or more, making an assumption can save lots of time since one number is fixed.

Comment: If X and Y might have a million digits (as you mentioned below) I doubt you'll ever get anything faster.  I guess you could pre-processing X into its prime factors, that might speed up the loop later, but the pre-processing is likely to be a sizable endeavor.

Comment: Seems reasonable when you are trying to see if a massive number is divisible by a massive number it takes some time.  Maybe look for other areas to optimize the code if performance is an issue.

Comment: Say X has last digit '3' and Y has last digit say '6', So, by no means Y can divide X completely. I'm thinking in this way but Unfortunately in my case X and Y both ended by 1, 3, 7 or 9.

Comment: Is Y likely to be smooth?

Comment: No, Y is a probable prime @harold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `BigInteger`s (like most numbers in computers since about 1980) are binary, so the only modulo that can be optimized by looking at the last 'digits' (binary digits = bits) are powers of 2, and the only power of 2 that is prime is 2<sup>1</sup>. `BigInteger.testBit(0)` tests that directly. However, most software that generates large should-be primes is for cryptography (like RSA, Rabin, DH, DSA) and ensures never to test an even candidate in the first place; see e.g. FIPS186-4 A.1.1.2 (or earlier).

Since your actual goal is not as stated in the title, but to test if one (large) integer is not divisible by *any* of several small primes, the mathematically fastest way is to form their product -- in general any common multiple, preferably the least, but for distinct primes the product *is* the LCM -- and compute its GCD with the candidate using [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). If the GCD is 1, *no* prime factor in the product is common with, and thus divides, the candidate. This requires several BigInteger divideAndRemainder operations, but it handles all of your tests in one fwoop.

A middle way is to 'bunch' several small primes whose product is less than 2<sup>31</sup> or 2<sup>63</sup>, take `BigInteger.mod` (or `.remainder`) that product as `.intValue()` or `.longValue()` respectively, and test that (if nonzero) for divisibility by each of the small primes using `int` or `long` operations, which are much faster than the `BigInteger` ones. Repeat for several bunches if needed. `BigInteger.probablePrime` and related routines does exactly this (primes 3..41 against a `long`) for candidates up to 95 bits, above which it considers an Erastosthenes-style sieve more efficient. (In either case followed by Miller-Rabin *and* Lucas-Lehmer.)

When measuring things like this in Java, remember that if you execute some method 'a lot', where the exact definition of 'a lot' can vary and be hard to pin down, all common JVMs will JIT-compile the code, changing the performance radically. If you *are* doing it a lot be sure to measure the compiled performance, and if you *aren't* doing it a lot the performance usually doesn't matter. There are *many* existing questions here on SO about pitfalls in 'microbenchmark(s)' for Java.

Comment: @user207421: IBM kept building decimal-based computers in the 1400 family through much of the 1960s. But 1980 does sound very late.

Comment: Turing mentions binary in his 1950 Conjecture paper, and Von Neurmann in his First Draft memo of 1945. I was using in myself in 1971, and was taught it in 1965 or so. Legend has it that the Russians tried ternary ... @HenningMakholm

Comment: @HenningMakholm+ S/360-370-390-Z (and competitors) kept packed-decimal going strong for a good while, although I don't have (and probably no one has) good statistics  which is why I said 'about'. Maybe we should just say 'well before Java was started', since that's what matters here. Cheer.

Answer (score 0):

There are algorithms to check divisibility but it's plural and each algorithm covers a particular group of numbers, e.g. dividable by 3, dividable by 4, etc. A list of some algorithms can be found e.g. at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule). There is no general, high performance algorithm that could be used for any given number, otherwise the one who found it would be famous and every dividable-by-implementation out there would use it.

Comment: I saw those divisible rules, not helpful in my case.

Comment: @ManojBanik Well, what is your case, actually?

Comment: Finding a faster way to check divisibility when the dividend is fixed. More precisely, to check for large number (potential to be prime) with many smaller primes before going to Lucas-Lehmer test. @Lothar.

Comment: @ManojBanik if you know that list of primes in advance then there are tricks

Comment: @ManojBanik the same tricks as normal for divisibility test with a constant divisor (not divisor rules, but multiplying by the modular multiplicative of the divisor modulo a power of two). But they don't work well for BigInteger if the divisors are small, because then "big%small" is faster to compute than "big*big". It would work for well for large known divisors, or for arithmetic with `long`.. so I guess this brings us back to no useful tricks (E: [here](https://ideone.com/5Gqarc) is an example)

Comment: @ManojBanik: You should edit your question with the details of your use case ("....More precisely, to check for large number (potential to be prime) with many smaller primes before going to Lucas-Lehmer test...."). It is important useful information.

Comment: Done. @James K Polk.